# How to use and authenticate the Last.fm API in Flutter Project

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, last.fm

I'm new to Flutter and using APIs. I'm trying to make a really simple Flutter app that would recommend the user similar tracks to a music track that they entered using the Last.fm API. I have an account with the API key and shared secret already. However, I'm not sure how to implement the Last.fm API. Every time that I try to get recommendations, nothing happens and I receive the error message:

> "flutter: Failed to authenticate or get similar tracks: Connection failed."

I know that it has something to do with the URL because when I click on the `'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/'` link, this is what the document tree looks like:

```
<lfm status="failed">
<style class="darkreader darkreader--safari-fallback">
html, body, body > :not(iframe) { background-color: #181a1b !important; border-color: #776e62 !important; color: #e8e6e3 !important; }
</style>
<error code="6">
Invalid parameters - Your request is missing a required parameter
</error>
</lfm>
```

Here is the main.dart code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class LastfmApi {
  final String baseUrl = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/';
  final String apiKey = 'API_KEY';
  final String secret = 'API_SECRET
  String? sessionKey;

  String _generateSignature(Map<String, String> params) {
    final sortedParams = Map.fromEntries(
        params.entries.toList()..sort((a, b) => a.key.compareTo(b.key)));
    final paramStrings =
        sortedParams.entries.map((e) => '${e.key}${e.value}').join('');
    final signature = utf8.encode(secret + paramStrings);
    return md5.convert(signature).toString();
  }

  Future<void> authenticate(String username, String password) async {
    final timestamp = (DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000).round();
    final params = {
      'api_key': apiKey,
      'method': 'auth.getMobileSession',
      'password': password,
      'username': username,
      'timestamp': timestamp.toString(),
    };
    params['api_sig'] = _generateSignature(params);

    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(baseUrl), body: params);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final session = jsonBody['session'];
      if (session != null) {
        sessionKey = session['key'];
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to authenticate');
      }
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to authenticate');
    }
  }

  Future<List<String>> getSimilarTracks(String track, String artist) async {
    if (sessionKey == null) {
      throw Exception('Not authenticated');
    }

    final timestamp = (DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000).round();
    final params = {
      'api_key': apiKey,
      'format': 'json',
      'limit': '10',
      'sk': sessionKey!,
      'method': 'track.getsimilar',
      'timestamp': timestamp.toString(),
      'track': track,
      'artist': artist,
      'autocorrect': '1',
    };
    params['api_sig'] = _generateSignature(params);

    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl +
        '?' +
        params.entries
            .map((e) => '${e.key}=${Uri.encodeComponent(e.value)}')
            .join('&')));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (jsonBody.containsKey('error')) {
        throw Exception(jsonBody['message']);
      }
      final tracks = jsonBody['similartracks']['track'] as List<dynamic>;
      final trackNames =
          tracks.map((track) => track['name'] as String).toList();
      return trackNames;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to get similar tracks');
    }
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Last.fm Music Recommendations',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _trackController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final LastfmApi _lastfmApi = LastfmApi();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title for recommendation'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: _trackController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Enter a track name',
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _usernameController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Enter your Last.fm username',
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _passwordController,
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Enter your Last.fm password',
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              try {
                await _lastfmApi.authenticate(
                    _usernameController.text, _passwordController.text);
                final recommendations = await _lastfmApi.getSimilarTracks(
                    _trackController.text, '');
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => RecommendationPage(
                        track: _trackController.text,
                        recommendations: recommendations),
                  ),
                );
              } catch (e) {
                print('Failed to authenticate or get similar tracks: $e');
              }
            },
            child: Text('Get recommendations'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RecommendationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String track;
  final List<dynamic> recommendations;

  RecommendationPage({required this.track, required this.recommendations});

  @override
  _RecommendationPageState createState() => _RecommendationPageState();
}

class _RecommendationPageState extends State<RecommendationPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

/*
  Future<void> _loadRecommendations() async {
    try {
      final recommendations = await getSimilarTracks(widget.track, '');
      setState(() {
        _recommendations = recommendations;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed to load recommendations');
    }
  }
*/
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Recommendations for ${widget.track}'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.recommendations.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final recommendation = widget.recommendations[index];

          return ListTile(
            leading: Image.network(recommendation['image'][2]['#text']),
            title: Text(recommendation['name']),
            subtitle: Text(recommendation['artist']['name']),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I know that the instructions are at this link: https://www.last.fm/api/mobileauth but I'm confused on how to implement it.

I tried changing the code so that it needs the last.fm username and password with three `TextEditingController` objects, `_trackController`, `_usernameController`, and `_passwordController`, which are used to capture the user's input for track name, username, and password. I thought it would authenticate the Last.fm API and get recommendations. But, nothing happens when I click the 'Get Recommendations' button.

Comment: Note that it is a bad idea to share your API secret in the internet. I've made a appropriate edit to your post.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked all your code but I've seen some parts that should be worth trying to do in another way according to the documentation.

1. You have a base URL for the API but when you call a certain method you need to append that path to the URL, too. For example: `http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/track.getSimilar`.
2. The endpoint methods are case sensitive, e.g. `track.getsimilar` != `track.getSimilar`
3. Note that for authenticating a mobile session you need to use the `https` variant of the API url as stated [in the documentation](https://www.last.fm/api/show/auth.getMobileSession). That is because you send the user's password over the wire.
4. From my understanding you don't need the `timestamp` as a parameter in the authentication request.
5. In your method for generating the `api_sig` (`_generateSignature`) you prepend the secret to the string but instead it should be appended: `final signature = utf8.encode(paramStrings + secret);`

These are some hints for improving the code. Let me know if this helped or if there are new problems have arisen.